# how do i adjust this turtle graphics drawing to draw around a circle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

with the current code, [this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0gUo.png).

but I'm trying to get it to look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJmSk.png), but not sure what to tweak.

```
#circle circle 

import turtle

turtle.colormode(255)

window=turtle.Screen()

draw=turtle.Turtle()
draw.pensize(2)
window.screensize(1200,1200)
draw.speed('fastest')
red, green, blue= 255, 255, 0


for shape in range(30):
    for circle in range(1):
        draw.circle(200)
    draw.penup()
    draw.forward(30)
    draw.pendown()
    draw.left(20)   
    green=green-5
    blue=blue+6
    draw.color(red, green, blue)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Make your circle radius smaller.

Comment: dont think that does it... I'm looking for how to have the circles touch the outline of an invisible center circle and draw from there on out, like the second image.

Comment: Can you experiment with it?  You've got the motion right... Now it comes down to tweaking the inner and outer dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice your two images, the one you want has the circles drawn outside the center, while the wrong one draws them around the center. Try changing `draw.left(20)` to `draw.right(20)` and adjust your values from there to get the sizes you want.

The change keeps the turtle outside of the circle just drawn, which is what you're looking for.